# Existence and Uniqueness Results for Second Order Linear Hyperbolic Equations on Unbounded Domains

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am studying second-order linear hyperbolic equations and their existence and uniqueness results. Most literature I've encountered discusses these results primarily in the context of bounded domains. I am curious to know if the existence and uniqueness results extend to hyperbolic equations defined on unbounded domains. Can anyone provide insights or recommend references that specifically address this aspect? I would be grateful for any information or pointers to relevant literature.

Comment: You might have a look at Chapter 2 of _Partial Differential Equations I_ by Egorov and Shubin.